# Fancybox: Unable to fix height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox

Am using Fancybox 1.2.6 and JQuery 1.2.6,

***Code:***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("a.iframe").fancybox({
            'width'             : 300,
            'height'            : 200,
            'type'              : 'iframe',
            'autoScale'         : false,
            'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
            'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
            'speedIn'           : 600, 
            'speedOut'          : 200, 
            'showCloseButton'   : false,
            'titleShow'         : false
        });

    });
</script>

<a class="iframe" id="iframe" href="test.html">iframe</a>
```

Here I am unable to fix the height and width of the window. Below i have attached the image of my output. Is there any way to fix the height and width ??

[image]

Comment: change the vaues of height and width

Comment: `'width': 300,
'height': 200` You can change these values

Comment: Already i tried those, but i don't find its working.

Comment: well, if the `height` is `200`, no surprise the image looks cropped. You would need a higher value. Got a link to see the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Set `autoDimensions` valut to `true or false`;

see http://fancybox.net/api for more details

also there is

```
$.fancybox.resize();
```

Comment: No i don't find its working with these changes. Is there any other way ?

Comment: In this case `autoScale` should be rather set to `false`